# Overwrite every record in database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to overwrite data every time when I set a new value or the same value in my database table. I have read a lot of articles but I don't quit e understand about UPDATE command yet.

this is just basis test file for an example test in my project.

**php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "00000000";
$dbname = "test";

//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$name = $_POST["name"];
$lastname =  $_POST["lastname"];

//echo $name," ",$lastname;

$insertsql = "UPDATE user SET name ='$name' lastname='$lastname' ";

if($conn->query($insertsql) === TRUE){

echo "update ok";
}

else{
echo "Error :" . $insertsql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


?>
```

**html**

```
<html>
</body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text"  value="" name="name">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" value="" name="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: also don't forget about the WHERE command. otherwise ALL Collumns get updated to that name :) $insertsql = "UPDATE user SET name ='$name', lastname='$lastname'  WHERE id = '$id'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update in your code:

```
$insertsql = "UPDATE user SET name ='$name' lastname='$lastname' ";
```

to

```
$insertsql = "UPDATE user SET name ='$name', lastname='$lastname' ";
```

use `comma(,) sign` if you want to update multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
`$insertsql = "UPDATE user SET name ='$name', lastname='$lastname' ";`
and where is `where` clause in your query.

Because this query update all the record in table.

Comment: I want to update all the record in my table every time becasue this is for changing my another config file. But Thank you very much for helping:)